# Ambiguity while including std class libraries

Tags: c++

I have Visual studio 2005 . One of my header file has a enum like

typedef enum { scalar, array, set } increment;

When I try to include the header file I get an ambiguity error for "set".
I am using the std::set in this cpp file . The issue is the compiler is unable to differentiate between the std::set and the set in the enum .

Any suggestions to resolve this ambiguity without declaring any new namespace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't import the std namespace into the global namespace.  The STL set is in the std namespace so if you don't have the line `using namespace std` in your headers you shouldn't get a conflict.  Beyond that, refactor your enum.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got `using namespace std;` in your file (or any headers it includes), that could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try prefixing your enum constant with something like "e"

enum E_increment { eScalar, eArray, eSet }

Answer (score -1):

The usual solution to this problem in C++ is to use more descriptive value names. For example, look at the Qt enum [GestureType](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qt.html#GestureType-enum). Its values are named like TapGesture and PanGesture, rather than just "Tap" and "Pan". In your case I suggest:

```
enum increment { scalar_increment, array_increment, set_increment };
```

In the next revision of C++ there will be a proper solution in the form of [strong enums](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#enum).